# Swift filter method with dictionaries

Tags: swift

I have an initial array of filter values, for example :

```
let filterValues : [String] = ["1", "4"]
```

I try to filter an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains an array of 1 dictionary or more.

The form of the array is the following :

```
  let test : [[String : AnyObject]] = [
        ["Objects":
            [
                [
                    "value":"1",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"1",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"1",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"4",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"2",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"2",
                    "test":"test"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        ["Objects":
            [
                [
                    "value":"4",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"2",
                    "test":"test"
                ],
                [
                    "value":"2",
                    "test":"test"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

What I want after applying the filter method on my initial test array :

```
    [
            ["Objects":
                [
                    [
                        "value":"1",
                        "test":"test"
                    ],
                    [
                        "value":"1",
                        "test":"test"
                    ],
                    [
                        "value":"1",
                        "test":"test"
                    ],
                    [
                        "value":"4",
                        "test":"test"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            ["Objects":
                [
                    [
                        "value":"4",
                        "test":"test"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

My code in playground :

```
//Filter objects with matching enabled filters
let filtered = test.filter({
    let currentObjects = $0["Objects"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    let currentsObjectsFiltered = currentObjects.filter({
        if let value = $0["value"] as? String {
            return filterValues.contains(value)
        }
        return false
    })
    print(currentsObjectsFiltered)
    return false
})
```

The array "`currentsObjectsFiltered`" is well filtered with the required values. But I want the original "`filtered`" array with the structure of the `test` array, not a new array which is simply filtered with the new objects. I don't know what to do with my filtered array "`currentsObjectsFiltered`"

I think that I must use it now that I have the objects sorted, but how...

**EDIT**

`currentsObjectsFiltered` output :

```
[["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 4, "test": test], ["value": 4, "test": test]]
[["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 1, "test": test], ["value": 4, "test": test], ["value": 4, "test": test]]
```

Don't pay attention to number of results values in the output I don't have the same test array, I just post the output to show you the structure of `currentsObjectsFiltered` which is well filtered.

I think I can't do it in one filter step, because the filter method is applied only to the children of the filtered array, not the children of the children. So I can just filter the "`Objects`" according a statement, I can't filter the children of "`Objects`" dictionaries, anybody can confirm that ?

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but the types are very annoying to work with. If you're finding yourself creating new `AnyObject` types, then you're almost certainly approaching the problem wrong. `AnyObject` mostly exists so you can deal with `id` types that come back from Cocoa. It's not a general-purpose type for Swift.

If you first would convert these to a type-safe struct, then all of this is much simpler and you won't have to constantly up-and-downcast everything into `AnyObject`.

Here's a simple struct that can be constructed from one of your dictionaries:

```
struct Object {
    let value: Int
    let test: String

    init?(jsonDictionary: [String: String]) {
        guard let
            value = jsonDictionary["value"].flatMap({Int($0)}),
            test = jsonDictionary["test"]
            else { return nil }

        self.value = value
        self.test = test
    }
}
```

Converting your whole data structure into this is straightforward:

```
let testArray = test.flatMap {
    ($0["Objects"] as? [[String: String]])?
        .flatMap(Object.init)
}
```

Then filtering it as you desire is much easier:

```
let filterValues = [1, 4]

let filtered = testArray.map { objects in
    return objects.filter { filterValues.contains($0.value) }
}
```

Even if you need the final result to involve `AnyObject`, I'd still do it this way, and then write a function to serialize it back to your original `AnyObject` structure. Working directly with `AnyObject` is just too error-prone and complicated. As an example of converting back to the `AnyObject` form, you could use a function like this:

```
func jsonArrayFromObjects(objectList: [[Object]]) -> [[String: AnyObject]] {
    return objectList.map { objects in
        ["Objects": objects.map { ["value": "\($0.value)", "test": $0.test] }]
    }
}
```

But I'd avoid this unless it were absolutely necessary. Even if you need a dictionary, it would be better to make this `[[String: [[String: String]]]` rather than `[[String: AnyObject]]`.